# Does the Secret Service consider Curse of Tippecanoe a threat to President-elect Biden?

Tags: united-states, president, secret-service

The [Curse of Tippecanoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_Tippecanoe) is the belief that US presidents who were elected in years that are evenly divisible by 20 are under threat of (violent) death in office. Despite it is only a belief that contains many inconsistencies, the political situation around the 2020 Presidential election is, indeed, disturbing.

**Does the US Secret Service consider the situation unusually dangerous to President-elect Biden?**
If so, what additional measures are taken for his security?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but if they do think so, I doubt it has anything to do with the so called curse of tippecanoe.

Comment: Sounds like baloney to me

Comment: Reagan was shot but didn't die.  The most violence faced by Bush as far as I recall was a shoe being thrown at him.  It seems that the curse died with JFK.

Comment: @phoog Read the wiki link. Apparently someone chucked a grenade at him: https://web.archive.org/web/20080704105908/http://www.cnn.com/2006/WORLD/europe/01/11/georgia.grenade/index.html How come I never heard about this?

Comment: Realistically, we don't have enough data to conclude that this is anything more than a statistical anomaly. For example, the NFC won the cointoss [14 superbowls in a row](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/29913/brief-history-super-bowl-coin-toss), but that doesn't mean they rigged the cointoss. In the real world these things happen, which is why I distrust any scientific study where p=0.05

Comment: Apparently, the NFC has won the coin flip 31 times out of 45. So  if we exclude their extraordinary streak of luck, they won 17 of the remaining times vs 13. Anyway, the probability of winning 31/45 or better by chance with a fair coin is around 1%. Not impossible considering our salience bias, but given other instances of sports cheating, perhaps we should ask ourselves what the prior probability of cheating is.

Comment: Given Biden's age, it's entirely plausible that he passes away while in office from a health-related cause.  The "curse" is just as likely to be a medical death as a violent one, historically (4-3).  There's not much the Secret Service can do about that.

Answer (score 7):

The Secret Service is a government agency staffed by professional law-enforcement personnel. They do not make institutional decisions based on superstition or magical thinking, any more than (say) the US Postal Service would refuse delivery to anyone who owns a black cat. At most, the Secret Service might recognize that *other people* are subject to odd notions of that sort, and add it to the list of reasons that deluded individuals might act out on their delusions, but they would not establish any new rules or procedures specifically based on such loose, speculative, histrionic associations.

I mean really, what would they do? Nail up horseshoes over every White House entrance? Throw themselves bodily at any ladder the president might accidentally walk under? Order their agents not to step on cracks in the sidewalk? As Sherlock Holmes once quipped, for cases like this "one might do better to consult a priest than a detective." The Service doesn't train its agents to fight malign cosmic forces; religions do.